# Capture functions using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am interested to capture all the following scenarios in a regex.

```
function (arg....)

function(arg....)

function     (arg...)

function
(
arg...

)
```

I don't care about spaces. so, they should be all capture. The only mandate is that the word function must be followed by open `(` and close `)`.

The regular expression should be smart to ignore space, carriage return as they don't matter for my need.

Any ideas?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://www.whathaveyoutriedsofar.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function[\s.]*\(([^\)]*)(\))
```

Group 1 will contain everything between the parenthesis. E.g:

[image: args_regex]